# wpf combobox - bind custom isselected property

Tags: wpf, combobox, selectedvalue

I want to bind a list of items with properties 'ID', 'Description' and 'IsSelected' to a combobox. The display value is set using DisplayMemberPath to 'Description' which works fine. However i want that 'IsSelected' property to be set when that item is selected. I've tried Setting SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue to 'IsSelected' but it doesn't work.

Comment: The Item is selected (not its ID or Description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to track the selected item in your view model, and keep it synced with the `ComboBox` by adding a two-way binding to `SelectedItem`.  When the view model property changes, update the `IsSelected` property of the new and previous selections.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing like re-answering a five year old question... I disagree with *Mike* in that you should keep track of both states as the ComboBox can give you the IsSelected state of the SelectedValue. *Matrix* was on the right lines but you can't use IsSelected with DisplayMemberPath.

With the code below my Fruits Selected property is bound to IsSelected.

**View Code**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruit}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFruitViewModel}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private FruitViewModel _selectedFruitViewModel;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.Fruit = new ObservableCollection<FruitViewModel>
        {
            new FruitViewModel { Name = "Pineapple", Selected = false },
            new FruitViewModel { Name = "Apple", Selected = false },
            new FruitViewModel { Name = "Orange", Selected = false },
            new FruitViewModel { Name = "Kiwi", Selected = false }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FruitViewModel> Fruit { get; }

    public FruitViewModel SelectedFruitViewModel
    {
        get => _selectedFruitViewModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedFruitViewModel, value);
    }
}
```

**FruitViewModel**

```
public class FruitViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool _selected;
    private string _name;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selected, value);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, 
                                          T value, 
                                          [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        return true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    <ComboBox Width="120" Height="35">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```